# computer graphics ,render depth image from many meshes and triangle

Tags: python, rendering, mesh, depth-map

how to do this?Given a scene consisting of 16000 triangles/meshes, for example, given 1000 cameras pose which expressed in 4x4 rotation matrix, how to quickly render 1000 depth image， does not need RGB information, but only the depth of each pixel (the distance from the camera optical center to a point in the scene), I have written a simple ray casting code, but it is too bad, Traverse 16000 triangles and calculate the intersection of 1224 * 1024 rays and these triangles each time，very slow，any suggestions?

I need to does this fast,the time of render 1000 depth images with 1224*1024 resolution which secne contains 16000 triangles need small than one day?

Comment: in blendr there is a depth layer and there is a camera (you got 1000?? camera's..why?, move a single cam) not sure how acurate the depth will be if it would be enough.
Keep the rest simple, in compositor convert the depth to bw picture (loosing some depth data)... i think you should play a bit with compositor, alternately there is backing for bump maps...

Comment: Can't help with Python, but for what you want, I would render in Eevee, since you don't actually need bounces.  There are actually many different ways to measure depth (distance from camera, distance from near clip plane projected toward the camera, distance from near clip plane projected toward the plane) but any of them could be done with a simple material, outputting emission without any view transform (or post processing render options) to .exr.  This will be pretty much an instantaneous render.  Can't help with converting camera matrices into actual camera transforms though, sorry.